# Can I re-use an oil filter for the short term?

Tags: motorcycle, oil-change

I’m currently changing my oil and was wondering if I could reuse the filter for just this weekend. I want to go to the local track this weekend and ride, can I get by with using the same filter for a couple of hours? I'm planning on changing the filter next week. The filter won’t arrive until Monday at the earliest.

The bike is a 2008 yz250f if that changes anything.

Comment: If the oil was changed on or before schedule, and the filter isn't in horrible condition (think 10,000 mile oil change on old engine) it should be fine. It's not idea, as it will dirty your clean oil a bit, but it won't be the end of the world, and I'm guessing there aren't many particulates or soot from blow by in your oil.

Comment: @the_storyteller you should really post that as an answer

Comment: A lot of Japanese bikes specify the oil filter every other oil change

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless you suspect some internal damage has occurred or that the filter is so massively blocked that it's restricting flow and causing pressure problems elsewhere - consider that it's a similar situation to having an engine that is worn and burns oil, and you top it up regularly with clean oil but don't change the filter every time you top it up

Comment: It used to be pretty customary to change filters every other oil change.  If the OP has been changing the oil and filter regularly I wouldn't anticipate any problems.  The heat from a track day will oxidize the oil enough to warrant more frequent changes, but there shouldn't be a lot of particles in it as long as the oil is doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry at all doing this.

Assuming the filter was replaced last oil change and the oil was still in good condition for its age on this oil change this should be fine.

Typically it is safe to replace an oil filter every second oil change, unless you have reason to believe it could be clogged (i.e. oil change very late), or don't know when it was last replaced.

If you are going to be doing a filter change next week, (seems like you already did the oil change), it should be fine, if re-using the oil from this oil change, make sure there are NO metal particles in it, otherwise just replace it with fresh oil.

Next time in this situation, it might be worth putting cheaper oil (that meats the standards required by engine of course) then when doing the filter change, put a really nice fully-synthetic brand in.
Especially if you are racing it often you want higher quality oil.